# Effect of source of river and its flow pattern on a budding civilization

Tags: culture, civilization, rivers

Rivers can either be rain-fed or snow-fed. And most of the bigger civilizations of the past were located on the river banks.

The climate of the region is temperate, but nearby there is a mountain range which has an average altitude of around 3500 metres. For the time being, let us assume that the planet is a earth-like planet with the diurnal cycles, the temperature zones and the land-water distribution is similar to that of earth. There is a single natural satellite circling around the planet, with it's size being twice that of our moon, while the distance is around 1.6 times that of the distance between earth and moon. The seasonal changes are slightly longer than that of the earth due to a larger orbit(Let's assume around 400 days to be a solar year).

The region is a peninsular region where the river empties into a sea. The salinity of the sea makes it non-drinkable.

**Given these constraints, how can the culture, pantheon and prioritized invention of a civilization which has developed on the banks of this region be impacted by a change in the following factors(keeping other factors constant)**:

1. Source of the river being from the mountain or from other
   sources(i.e. rain-fed or snow-fed),
2. Flood cycle (Please also elucidate on the cause of flood cycle changes),
3. Mineral constitution of the land at the source of the river?

**EDIT:** Narrowing the context of the question, is their any behavioural trends in the pantheon and the technological advancement of a civilization, dependent on the aforementioned factors, keeping the other factors and the previously stated constraints unchanged? If so, what is the correlation?

Comment: This question looks interesting but is unfortunately far too broad to be answerable in its current state.  Asking us to elucidate upon the effects of changes in rivers on the culture of an entire civilization is unanswerable without the needing an answer the size of an encyclopedia.  Perhaps focussing on a specific aspect of the culture could make this question more acceptable.

Comment: The last paragraph, is it supposed to be a question? There are some many things wrong with this post.

Comment: Hello Elkosh and welcome to Worldbuilding! If you haven't already done it, you may want to take the [tour] in order to become acquainted with the purpose and expectations of this site. In particular, this site favors questions which have *one* correct answer, and questions which can be answered in a reasonable space. This question will certainly seen as too broad and opinion based; you may want to refine it. For example, consider just *two* rivers: the real Nile and the maybe-real-maybe-magical [Sarasvati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarasvati_River)...

Comment: Ok.
I will definitely try to refine this to articulate my feelings better.

Comment: I also need to say that at first sight what the question asks *is not really known*. We *don't know* and *cannot predict* how a civilization and its material culture develop based only on the geographical conditions prevailing on its territory. I seriously doubt that we will ever be able to do so. It is most likely that the development of Asimovian [psychohistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_(fictional)) is not really possible.

Comment: This question (even after the edit) is MASSIVE and not suitable for Stack Exchange sites.  "Pantheon" in my experience has religious connotations.  The phrase "prioritized invention of a civilization" means absolutely nothing to me.  The Q doesn't even tell us the tech level of the city or anything about its demographics.  Stack Exchange likes specific questions that can receive specific answers averaging a handful of paragraphs.  If this Q could be answered, it would take a ream of paper.  Why are you even asking this?  What are you actually looking for?